# How to control height of minipages, when using multiple rows

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

I'm using minipages to create a newcommand that allows me row entries in a CV, because I can't use the documentclass that would make this easier.  Each set of minipages is one entry in the CV.

The problem I am having is with the spacing of the minipages.  Between one row to the next, it seems the spacing changes.  The sets of minipages are far apart (vertically) if it is only one line, but if the page has multiple lines they are too close together.  Is there anyway I can fix this?  Here is the code I am using.   The ifthenelse, is helping me leave out the commas if there no entry for a certain parameter.

```
\newcommand{\cventry}[6]{
\begin{minipage}[t]{.2\linewidth}
\begin{flushright}
  #1
\end{flushright} \
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.75\linewidth}
\textbf{#2}\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{,} \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{\textit{#3}}\ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{,} \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{{#4}}\ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{,} \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{{#5}}\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{,} \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{{#6}}
\end{minipage}
}
```

Thoughts?

Update:  There was an extra "\" after the \end{flushright} that I just noticed.   Removing that was all it took.  Apparently that was the only thing messing it up.  Sorry for the unnecessary question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a small typo was the source of the problem